# how to let users to select columns in a database table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database, connection-string

We are trying to build an web application that allows users to select appropriate columns for given database table.

I wonder if there is any API for these - I've googled it a while in vain. Otherwise, if you can give some clues (patterns or sample codes) how to build such a component, that will be great and appreciated.

Comment: You will need to read from the sql system tables. Open your sql console and browse your database with the SQL profiler listening, it will give you great hint on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could base your application on INFORMATION_SCHEMA views/table. This is  documentation for SQL Server, but you can easily find it for other databases too:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186778.aspx

Sample SQLs:

```
select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES

select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'users'
```

if you want to use this solution with many databases, to separate your application from db engine, you can create about defining IMetadataProvider interface and create implementations for different databases:

```
interface IMetadataProvider {
    ...GetTables();
    ...GetTableColumns();
    ...GetTableRelations();
    //Other functions required by your project
}
```

You can also create your own query builder interface:

```
interface IQueryBuilder {
    ...From(string tableName);
    ...Top(int numberOfRows); //TOP for SQL SERVER, LIMIT for MySQL
}
```

Comment: OK. I guess I can encapsulate that for other database server. That makes sense. Thanks