# Is it possible to use Entity Framework for unknown database tables?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ado.net

User selects a database and its table, and will browse the table in a web application. Can I achieve that with Entity Framework? I know EF is ORM framework but in this case, I may not create edmx file for each selection. Even if I did it, how do I create, say, POCO objects dynamically according to the table? What should I do in this case? Do I have to go with low-level ADO.NET?

Comment: If it's as simple as letting a user select a table name and browse it (a select *), why even bother with Entity Framework? Will the application be read only, or will the user make changes to the tables? I wouldn't consider ADO.net to be low level either...

Comment: How will you populate the list of tables that the user can select from? From sysobjects table?

Comment: @mservidio, As for selecting a table, any way would be fine (dropdown, listbox, even radio buttons). Exactly EF or not is my question. my grid will be read-only table. What's your verdict?

Comment: In the other question/answer ( http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7123326/how-to-let-users-to-select-columns-in-a-database-table), somebody told me to implement IMetadataProvider to read the list of tables.

Comment: I was going to say to just query the sysobjects table to get all table names. You could filter what comes back from that easily. Then just build up a query string, and query the tables using ado.net to bind to your components... the other example similarly uses Information_Schema.Tables... same thing...

Comment: @mservidio, I am leaning to your suggestion. If possible, please answer with more (or not) details below so I can accept it.Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think Entity Framework is unnecessary in this case. It *might* certainly be possible to use EF for something like this, but if it's a simple case of just getting a list of available table names from the database, and letting the user select a table to view, I would simply do the following:

Create drop down list on the site, and populate it using result from query:

```
SELECT table_name FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES t
```

Then after the user selects an item from the dropdown, you can bind your grid using Ado.net. Something like:

```
string tableName = "get value from dropdown";  
DataTable dt = new DataTable();

using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection("connection string here"))
{
    string sql = string.Format("select * from {0}", tableName);
    SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
    da.Fill(dt);
}

// bind dt to your grid or gui component here.
```

Comment: A lot more to be done but I think your approach makes sense. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

**Edit** Well I know you can do this at least partially. You can definitely let the user select a database/table because you can provide your own connection string/EntityConnect object to the Contexts constructor. I'm not sure how you can go about creating entities dynamically though, I think you would have to have an edmx file that already has all the entities generated or write them yourself from before.

Comment: Yeah, that's what I thought and maybe I don't even want to create those entities for browsing.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to point EF at each database first, rather than expecting EF to dynamically look at a new database in your application.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I think I understand what you are saying but could you elaborate more?

Comment: No problem. I don't understand how EF could dynamically create entities for a database that the application isn't already aware of.